# Draw all the Non-Client area in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, gdi

I am looking to draw my non-client area in C#, for example, instead a rectangle as a form, i want an ellipse (this is an example), but how can i do it?

I basically want to draw all my non client area, and i think to do that i will have to override some methods, but which ones?

I have found an example that uses 'xaml', what i think that is windows presentation foundation app, but i haven't understand it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

m0sa has provided [a WPF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254161/draw-all-the-non-client-area-in-c/5254269#5254269) already.

For WinForms, you'll need to process the `WM_NCPAINT` message (override `Control.WndProc`) and also enable the layered window style in order to have transparent regions in the bounding box.

Comment: I have been trying some things in WinForms based in some examples i have found, but something i can't understand is how can i verify which message i have received in the override method WndProc? I have found an example that have something that looks like a enumerator called Win32Calls, but how i get the Win32Calls?

Comment: @Miguel: `WndProc` has a parameter of type `Message`.  `Message` has a property "Msg".  Check if that is equal to 0x85 (the value of `WM_NCPAINT`).  pinvoke.net lists values for many WinApi constants.

Comment: My problem was working with the message, comparing it with what, but now i know how i can do this in WinForms. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking Winforms, and want to *draw* in the Non Client area, Ben's suggestion will work.

If you want your window a different shape - say Round like a clock, then you will be looking at Regions.

```
    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddEllipse(100, 100, 100, 100);
    this.Region = new Region(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the window xaml file like this

```
<Window x:Class="[YourwindowClass]"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="..." 
  WindowStyle="None" 
  AllowsTransparency="True" 
  Background="Transparent">
    [Draw the window]
</Windows>
```

You will need to generate your own click handlers for dragging the window though. There are some examples [here](http://buksbaum.us/2009/02/28/irregular-shaped-windows-in-wpf/) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/shapedWindow10292009222424PM/shapedWindow.aspx).

Comment: This is a good way to do it, the best in my opinion, working with WPF. Thanks for the suggestion, and the explanation.

Comment: This is not a good idea because the window will be software rendered if you set AllowTransparency="True". To verify this, open Task Manager and open your window. Move your mouse pointer over this window. You will see that your CPU usage will jump to 30-40%. Just for moving the mouse over the window.

Comment: i will check that out. tnx for the insight!